# Grid Field Type PHP Error

Tags: grid

I got the following error after using the grid fieldtype.[image] I started over and it went away. However, it happened again the next day when I went in and add ed another row. Again, I starred over again and its working now. Any ideas on how to fix it? Running 2.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this in the bug reports at ellislab.com : https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20284/when-going-to-edit-an-entry-with-a-grid-field-on-it-i-get-php-and-mysql-err

> Known Solution
>
> The problem happens when an extra empty column gets added to the grid.
>   It has no name, no short name, no data at all.  It’s impossible to add
>   an empty column through the editor, but it looks like it’s cropped up
>   due to some third party add-ons.
>
> Just delete the null column in the field editor (Admin- Channel Admin-
>   Channel Fields) and you should be good.